# Dynamo DB and JPA together in Spring Boot project error Not a managed type: class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I made a Spring Boot Dynamo DB project just like [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-dynamodb) and another Spring Boot project using JPA.

Now I´m trying to load the JPA project inside the Dynamo DB project through Maven, like that:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>utils.br.com.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>                            
        </dependency>
```

And I´m getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type:
>   class dynamo.br.com.xxx.model.Customer

My main class of Dynamo DB project

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DynamoSpringBootWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DynamoSpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The important part of application.properties from JPA Project:

```
entitymanager.packagesToScan=utils.br.com.xxx.model
```

My JPA database config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String USERNAME;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Bean(name = "xxxDataSource")
    public DataSource xxxDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "xxxSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean analistaSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(gurgelDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "xxxTransactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager analistaTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(analistaSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Any ideas of what´s going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding annotation `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "your.package.base.*" })` on `DynamoSpringBootWebApplication ` class?

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` already provides `@ComponentScan`